# copying files using php over slow server

Tags: php, copy

i am trying to copy multiple videos from another website to my website. i am using php curl method (i have also tried file_put_contents method)

but its taking aa lot of time for single file. video size is max 6 to 7mb per videos.

i think the problem is with remote site. that site is giving low download speed approximately 140kb.

so is there any way to copy files fast? its now taking 2-3 minutes for 4 mb files.

can i copy that file using multiple connections like idm?

Comment: sounds like your downloading from the streaming side of script and not directly, which would most likely have throttling on, use sftp/scp or some other method that directly access the file, if that's slow then there is not much else you can do other than to wait

Comment: why not use ftp?

Answer (score 0):

Download them with ftp. It may be fast.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php